# OneNote API, Unknown User

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote-api

I'm looking for a solution to hide (or at least change) the "UU" (Unknown User) in the Microsoft OneNote application, when the page has been feed using the Microsoft Graph API with an application access (The application edits the OneNote on his own).

[small view of what appends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouUQE.png)

[when right clicking on "UU"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mFzs.png)

I know there is a solution to disable it on each page in the OneNote app, but my app generates a lot of pages.
Anyone who have achieve disable or change this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. As there isn't an authenticated user, there is no way for OneNote to know who to attribute a given change too.

Assuming you're creating these pages in a small number of notebooks, you can select ["Disable History for this Notebook"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_other/can-i-turn-off-versioning-tracking-authors-marking/9e4a8104-d57b-41da-9484-afaa99130f77) under the Recycle Bin and turn off versioning/tracking altogether.